# DevExpress report: Dynamic groups don't work as expected

Tags: c#, dynamic, devexpress, report

I've been working with a C# application that should show a report with dynamic groups they could go since 0 to "N", so I use a `foreach` loop to manage all, the code is the following:

```
private void AgregarAgrupaciones()
{
    if (Agrupaciones == null)
        return;

    DataSet dataSource = (DataSet) DataSource;

    GroupHeader1.Level = 0;
    int level = 1;

    foreach (var agrupacion in Agrupaciones.Reverse())
    {
        GroupHeaderBand grupoDinamico = new GroupHeaderBand();
        XRLabel labelAgrupacion = new XRLabel();
        labelAgrupacion.Text = agrupacion.Value;
        grupoDinamico.Controls.Add(labelAgrupacion);
        grupoDinamico.Height = 0;

        XRLabel labelValorAgrupacion = new XRLabel();
        labelValorAgrupacion.Text = "";
        XRBinding binding = new XRBinding("Text", null, "Inasistencias.Empleado_Inasistencias." + agrupacion.Value);
        labelValorAgrupacion.DataBindings.Add(binding);
        labelValorAgrupacion.Location = new Point(100, 0);
        grupoDinamico.Controls.Add(labelValorAgrupacion);

        string campoDb = "Inasistencias.Empleado_Inasistencias.";
        campoDb = campoDb + (agrupacion.Value == "Grupo Personal" ? "GrupoPersonalNombre" :  agrupacion.Value);
        GroupField campo = new GroupField(campoDb, DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
        grupoDinamico.GroupFields.Add(campo);
        grupoDinamico.Level = level;
        level++;
        Bands.Add(grupoDinamico);
    }
}
```

The previous code it would actually show in the report the name of the groups, but it is not really grouping, example:

Having the following table

[image: table]

The expected result would be:

- Group 1 Sales
- Group 2 Office 1
- Group 3 Building 1

  - John Smith
  - Richard Anderson
- Group 2 Office 2
- Group 3 Building 1

  - Michel Ferrer
- Group 2 Office 2
- Group 3 Building 1

  - Martha Stevenson
- Group 1 Marketing
- Group 2 Office 3
- Group 3 Building 1

  - Pamela Murier

And instead that, im getting this:

- Group 1 Sales
- Group 2 Office 1
- Group 3 Building 1

  - John Smith
  - Richard Anderson
  - Michel Ferrer
  - Martha Stevenson
  - Pamela Murier

Note: The method that fills the groups is being called through the report "before print" action and I already checked that the datasource contains all the values I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code after previewing

```
GroupHeaderBand band = XtraReportToPreview.Bands[BandKind.GroupHeader] as GroupHeaderBand;
if (band != null)
{
        band.GroupFields.Clear();
        band.GroupFields.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.GroupField[] 
        {
        // Set your condition for dynamic group by for each GroupField 
        new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.GroupField("Customer", DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRColumnSortOrder.Ascending)
        });
}
```